# Why isn't my object being updated

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm doing something wrong because after the loop executed myData still contains objects with blank ids.  Why isn't the myData object being updated in the following foreach loop, and how do I fix it?

I thought it could be that I wasn't passing the object by reference, but added a ref keyword and also moved to the main method and I'm still showing the object not being updated.

**Additional Information**

The user object in the foreach loop is being updated, but the myData list does not reflect the updates I see being applied to the user object.

** Solution **
I was not creating a List but an Enumerable which was pulling the json each time I went through myData in a foreach list.  Adding a ToList() fixed my issue.

```
public class MyData
{
     public string ID { get; set; }
     public Dictionary<string, string> Properties { get; set; }
}

int index = 0;
// Does not allow me to up, creates an IEnumerable
//IEnumerable<MyData> myData = JObject.Parse(json)["Users"]
//                                    .Select(x => new MyData()
//                                            {
//                                                ID = x["id"].ToString(),
//                                                Properties = x.OfType<JProperty>()
//                                                               .ToDictionary(y => y.Name, y => y.Value.ToString())
//                                            });

//Works allows me to update the resulting list.
IEnumerable<MyData> myData = JObject.Parse(json)["Users"]
                                    .Select(x => new MyData()
                                            {
                                                ID = x["id"].ToString(),
                                                Properties = x.OfType<JProperty>()
                                                               .ToDictionary(y => y.Name, y => y.Value.ToString())
                                            }).ToList();

foreach (var user in myData) // Also tried myData.ToList()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.ID))
    {
        user.ID = index.ToString();
        user.Properties["id"] = index.ToString();
    }

    index++;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.ID))` instead? Are you sure that the ID isn't null (instead of empty)?

Comment: where is mydata updated?

Comment: That last `user.ID` should likely be `index`

Comment: Yes, I have, just was lazy in creating my example, I'll update to reflect.

Comment: @JBKing Shouldn't matter, since `user.ID` and `index` should be equal at that point

Comment: Is `myData` the result of a linq query? If so it will be re-created on each traversal of the sequence.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin, even when the id property of user has been removed?

Comment: This looks like a tool for...basic debugging.

Comment: Something seems to be missing from your example code. As far as we can tell, myData isn't populated with anything.

Comment: @JBKing You can't remove a property. The code is removing an item from a dictionary, then setting that same index to a different value. Not sure why OP can't just do `user.Properties["id"] = index`

Comment: Show the code that sets `myData`.  As it stands the code you show shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Also, step 1 of any process here is to use your debugger.  Put break points on the relevant lines, run it in debug mode and watch what's actually going on.

Comment: I've been walking through the debugger and tried quite a few different options and am not seeing what I'm doing wrong. and with myData not updating I'm questioning whether what I'm trying to do is even possible with C#.  I've updated to use @AsadSaeeduddin suggestions, and it is still not updating.

Comment: @user2197446 How are you checking that it's updated?

Comment: I'm stepping through in the Visual Studio debugger. I can see user getting the updated values, but when I look at the myData object, it still contains a blank ID for the object.

Comment: `myData` is an enumerable. Every time you iterate it you create the objects from the JSON again. You need to put a `ToList` at the end of the `JObject.Parse` etc. statement.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I would never have seen that, but adding a ToList fixes it.  Now how do I give you credit for it?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MyData
{
    public MyData() 
    {
       this.Properties = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Properties { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IEnumerable<MyData> myDataList = new List<MyData>();
    int index = 0; // Assuming your starting point is 0
    foreach (var obj in myDataList)
    {
        if (obj != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ID))
        {
            obj.ID = index.ToString();
            // Checks if the Properties dictionary has the key "id"
            if (obj.Properties.ContainsKey("id"))
            {
               // If it does, then update it
               obj.Properties["id"] = obj.ID;
            }
            else
            {
               // Else add it to the dictionary
               obj.Properties.Add("id", obj.ID);
            }
        }
        index++;
    }
```

I believe the reason why your objects are not updating because it's probably still referring to the memory block before your objects were changed. Perhaps. The easiest way (that I can think of, there are thousands of smarter programmers than me) is to create a new list and have it contain all of your updated objects.

**Edit**
I updated the code above with the code that I have. I created a method to set a small amount of objects to test:

```
private static IEnumerable<MyData> GetMyData()
{
    return new List<MyData>() 
    {
        new MyData(),
        new MyData() {ID = "2"},
        new MyData() {ID = "3"},
        new MyData()
    };
}
```

I was able to view my changes and then go through a `foreach` loop to view my changes. If the ID of the object is Null or Empty, then it steps into the if check and adds the current `index` to the ID as you know.

Now for my question: Which "id" is blank? The "id" in the dictionary or is it the ID of the model? Are all of your (Model).ID blank? As the updated code of yours, if your dictionary doesn't have "id" as a key, it's going to throw an exception saying it doesn't exist so you will need to do a check to make sure it does exist or add it if it doesn't.

Comment: This really gets to the heart of my question. Should I be able to update the objects I'm iterating through in a foreach loop.  Everything I see points to that being possible, but yet I can't get it to work, and I think I should be able to do this without creating a new list.